# Как синхронизировать доступ к двум объектам из разных потоков, если последовательность доступа может быть разной в разных потоках?

Tags: c++, mutex

Нужно написать функцию, которая переводит деньги с одного счета на другой.

```
struct Account {
    mutex mx;
    double amount;
};

void transfer(Account& from, Account& to, double value);
```

Эта функция может вызываться одновременно из разных потоков

Comment: Если у вас всего 2 потока, то сделайте еще один mutex (на `transfer()`) и лочьте его в начале `transfer()`. / Если потоков много (т.е. вы хотите, чтобы несколько не пересекающихся по счетам вызовов работали одновременно), то придется переработать алгоритм и сделать порядок доступа одним и тем же.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае можно добиться строго одинаковой последовательности доступа путем сравнения указателей на объекты для определения порядка:

```
void transfer(Account& from, Account& to, double value)
{
     auto p_first{::std::addressof(from)};
     auto p_second{::std::addressof(to)};
     if(p_first == p_second)
     {
         return;
     }
     auto const address_first{reinterpret_cast<::std::uintptr_t>(p_first)};
     auto const address_second{reinterpret_cast<::std::uintptr_t>(p_second)};
     if(address_first > address_second)
     {
          ::std::swap(p_first, p_second);
     }
     ::std::lock_guard<::std::mutex> const lock_first{p_first->mutex};
     ::std::lock_guard<::std::mutex> const lock_second{p_second->mutex};
     from.amount -= value;
     to.amount += value;
}
```

Comment: а проще адреса нельзя получить?

Comment: @cassius Нет. оператор & может быть перегружен и поэтому использовать его для получения именно адреса не следует.

Answer (score 1):

В C++17 можно залочить 2 мьютекса так:

```
std::scoped_lock lck{from.mx, to.mx};
```